# confused with definition of of QBluetoothLocalDevice::allDevices()

Tags: c++, qt

`QBluetoothLocalDevice::allDevices()` it show the list of available devices.
I do not understand what it means

1. the list of available devices to pair to
2. some kind of internal bluetooth servers

Answer (score 1):

None of those two. It returns the devices locally connected to your device that are capable of establishing a bluetooth connection. Think of a bluetooth dongle etc etc. You need a network card to get internet acccess the same way you need a bluetooth "card" to get access to bluetooth. Such "cards" are called devices that `allDevices()` return.